# Flutter WebView Loading Time

Tags: ios, flutter, flutter-layout

I am currently implementing use of the [flutter_webview_plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) and it currently takes around 2-4 seconds for each webpage to load. Can anyone suggest how one might improve the loading time for webview?